# Initialize a string with a named constant in C++

Tags: c++, c-strings

Can I use something to initialize a c-string except an explicit string literal?

```
struct Person {
    char name[40];
};

constexpr char PRESIDENT[] = "George Bush";
Person somebody { "George Bush" }; //Ok
Person president { PRESIDENT }; //the value of type "const char* " cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char"
```

Of course, I still can use #define, but it's not the best idea.

Comment: becomes "the value of type "const char* " cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "const char" "

Comment: Actually, it works if 
Person president { PRESIDENT[0],   PRESIDENT[1],   PRESIDENT[2], etc  }
but it's definitely not what I'm searching for!

Comment: Arrays are dumb as rocks for reasons that made sense back in the 1970s. Since the 1990s the rule of thumb has been to avoid them as much as possible.

Comment: The C++ standard has specific rules for initializing a `char[]` array from a string literal. It does not have the same rules for initializing a `char[]` array from a non-literal `const char[]` array, or from a `const char*` pointer (which your `PRESIDENT` decays into). It *is* possible to initialize a `std::array` from another `std::array`, but only if they have the same size

Answer (score 1):

Note `std::array` should be preferred over built in array here as one `std::array` can be initialized from another `std::array` of the same size directly.

---

Given this, it is still possible to achieve what you want by adding a **constructor template** as shown below:

```
#include <cstddef> //for std::size_t

struct Person {
    char name[40]; 
    //constructor template
    template<std::size_t N>
    Person(const char (&arr)[N])   
    {
         for(int i = 0; i < 40 && i < N;i++)
         {
             name[i] = arr[i];
         }
    }
};
int main()
{
    constexpr char PRESIDENT[] = "George Bush";  
    Person president { PRESIDENT };    //works now

}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sfvzf5YMd)